# Deleting a Firestore entry based on FIFO

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, collections, snapshot

I'm trying to create a script that deletes a record from a Firestore collection using a FIFO (First In First Out approach).

So if there are three matching results in the collection, the script should take the first one added and just delete that one (leaving the remaining two). My code is:

```
_firestore
                                      .collection('myCollection')
                                      .where('uid',
                                          isEqualTo: _auth.currentUser.uid)
                                      .where('field',
                                          isEqualTo: widget.field)
                                      .orderBy('Posted', descending: false)
                                      .limit(1)
                                      .get()
                                      .then((querySnapshot) {
                                    querySnapshot.docs
                                        .forEach((documentSnapshot) {
                                      _firestore
                                          .collection('myCollection')
                                          .doc(documentSnapshot.id)
                                          .delete();
                                    });
                                  });
```

(**Just to note:** 'Posted' is the date the entry was added) Unfortunately this doesn't work, and all three results remain in the collection.

If though I use this script instead, then all three results are removed from the collection:

```
_firestore
                                          .collection('myCollection')
                                          .where('uid',
                                              isEqualTo: _auth.currentUser.uid)
                                          .where('field',
                                              isEqualTo: widget.field)
                                          .get()
                                          .then((querySnapshot) {
                                        querySnapshot.docs
                                            .forEach((documentSnapshot) {
                                          _firestore
                                              .collection('myCollection')
                                              .doc(documentSnapshot.id)
                                              .delete();
                                        });
                                      });
```

An example of an entry in my collection is as follows:

[image: My Collection]

So I know the logic, connection, fields etc... are all correct, but why does the first example not work?

Comment: I reproduced this but after creating the required index I had no problem doing what you were trying to do. Did you make sure they were fully built?

Answer (score 0):

Have you check you logs? I am pretty sure that Firebase is throwing an error saying that your collection need indexes with a link.
Just follow the link and the instruction to build the indexes. Once complete you should be able to do what you are looking for.

More info about Indexes: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing

and Simple queries / Coumpound queries: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It appears as if the Single Field indexes were created (and allowing Ascending and Descending searches). I did though also add a Composite Index for the relevant field. It has been built - but it's still not working ?

Comment: nothing in the output? also have you tried to print the result of the querysnapshot to be sure it's not empty?

Comment: Nothing in output. It can't be empty because the second example code does delete all the matching entries (so it is finding them). It just doesn't seem to find one if I sort by a field and limit the results to just one entry (?)